# How to emulate friendship in C#?

Tags: c#, friend

I would like to declare that (only) class A can access/manipulate (some of) members of class B. How to achieve this, when there is no `friend` existing in `C#`?

Comment: I was hoping for human-computer-interface tag =). On the more serious note, wasn't this mechanism purposely skipped because it usually indicate or led to bad designs? I think the closes and most proper way is to define inner-classes.

Comment: There are some very long discussions regarding the goodness vs badness of `friend`ship. I find it useful and would hesitate to call it bad. Anyway, this whole text raised as a finalization of a pattern I needed to implement to achieve customer requirements and I thought it might be helpful for someone.

Comment: Is there any reason you would prefer to avoid `internal`?

Comment: From my point of view `internal` is too general. As far as I know, any class in the same assembly can access any of the internals.

Comment: @sharpener: Right, and *you know the names of everyone who is going to work on that assembly*. You solve the problem by asking those people to keep their hands off class B, and you give them a good business-focused reason why they should do so.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Unfortunately this is not so true, although I could wish it. The people are different, having different skills and I'm not the one who makes decisions in terms of future source code usage. So if there is possibility to "restrict" or "enforce" some usage on the language/source code level (not only the documentation) I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the possibilities is following (hopefully it could save some thinking for someone). This is applicable for those who:

- don't like (don't want to use) `internal` or `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`.
- don't like (don't want to use) reflection to extract and exploit "internals".

Description:

- Let classes `A` and `B` deal on some agreement (interface) which allows `A` to manipulate "internals" of `B`.
- Let `B` defines non-public methods implemementing this agreement (similar like just standard interface implementation, but using `private`/`protected` methods - which prohibits standard usage of `interface` implementation).
- Let `B` creates a dedicated object containing delegates initialized to members of this agreement (effectively exporting selected "internals").
- Pass this object from `B` to `A` (ideally without need of any user interference) to grant `A` the right to manipulate `B`.
- Use it in `A` effectively allowing whatever what `B` was willing to provide.

Advantages:

- Less space for accidental unwanted change of anytning in `B` (in opposite of the case all is `internal` or `public`).
- Precise control of what can be done from `A` in `B`.

Disadvantages:

- Little more complicated (agreement definition, need of the agreement passing process).
- `A` still provides public infrastructure method (registration), which, improperly called, might cause some harm.

Example for the code seekers:

- Let `A` is a technician who is able to repair a phone
- Let `B` is a smartphone which provides standard (`public`) features also as some know-how for doing basic repairs.
- A user is able to utilize standard features, a `Technician` (as a `SmartPhone's friend`) can utilize advanced features.

  ```
  /*
   * SmartPhone<-Technician friendship contract
   */
  public class SmartPhoneServiceActivities
  {
      public delegate bool ReplaceGlassHandler  (SmartPhone device);
      public delegate bool ReplaceDisplayHandler(SmartPhone device);

      public ReplaceGlassHandler   ReplaceGlass {get;}
      public ReplaceDisplayHandler FactoryReset {get;}

      public SmartPhoneServiceActivities(ReplaceGlassHandler replaceGlass, ReplaceDisplayHandler factoryReset)
      {
          ReplaceGlass = replaceGlass;
          FactoryReset = factoryReset;
      }
  }

  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  public class SmartPhone
  {
      #region Friend functions
      /*
       * Provide private functions for "trusted" classes
       */
      static SmartPhone()
      {
          var services = new SmartPhoneServiceActivities(ReplaceGlass, FactoryReset); // SmartPhone<-Technician agreement regarding "private modifications"

          Technician.RegisterDeviceForRepair(typeof(SmartPhone), services);
      }

      protected static bool ReplaceGlass(SmartPhone device)
      {
          device.IsDamagedGlass = false;
          return true; // Skilled technicians only ;)
      }

      protected static bool FactoryReset(SmartPhone device)
      {
          device.IsDamagedSoftware = false;
          return true;
      }
      #endregion



      #region Standard public usage
      public bool IsDamaged => IsDamagedGlass || IsDamagedSoftware;
      public bool IsDamagedGlass    {get; protected set;}
      public bool IsDamagedSoftware {get; protected set;}

      public void Call() {}

      public void DropIt()
      {
          var isBroken = (new Random((int)(DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds)).Next() & 3;

          IsDamagedGlass    = (isBroken & 1) != 0;
          IsDamagedSoftware = (isBroken & 2) != 0;
      }
      #endregion
  }

  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  public class Technician
  {
      protected static readonly Dictionary<Type, SmartPhoneServiceActivities> knowHow = new Dictionary<Type, SmartPhoneServiceActivities>();

      /*
       * Although this is public and improper call might cause inability of a class to register it's acceptable "risk". 
       * It's intended for static constructors invocation.
       */
      public static void RegisterDeviceForRepair(Type deviceType, SmartPhoneServiceActivities services)
      {
          if (   (!knowHow.ContainsKey(deviceType))
              && (services != null))
          {
              knowHow[deviceType] = services;
          }
      }

      public bool Repair(SmartPhone device)
      {
          var isRepaired = false;
          var deviceType = device.GetType();

          if (knowHow.ContainsKey(deviceType))
          {
              var services  = knowHow[deviceType];
              var isSoftOk  = !device.IsDamagedSoftware || services.FactoryReset(device);
              var isGlassOk = !device.IsDamagedGlass    || services.ReplaceGlass(device);

              isRepaired = isSoftOk && isGlassOk;
          }

          return isRepaired; 
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Is this pattern meant to prevent against carelessness/incompetence, or is it supposed to protect against malice?  For carelessness/incompetence: Can you say for certain that your static constructor will run before my `IdiotPhone`'s constructor, which registers the `Smartphone` type accidentally? In the case of malice: Let's say I'm an `EvilTechnician` bent on world domination. What's to stop me from just grabbing the dictionary with reflection, clearing it, installing myself as the repair overlord and doubling the cost of a repair?

Comment: @theB: the first one. It's far from ideal, bur this is the best I was able to come up with (and this is also the reason I tried to get some improvements from here).

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to declare that **only** class A can access/manipulate **some of** members of class B.

The highlighted words indicate the problematic points.

First off, I assume that by "only class A" you actually mean "only class A and class B". Code in a member declared in class B can always access all members of class B, so class A will *never* be the **only** class that can access a member of B.

One technique would be to make class A the sole nested class of class B. Now classes A and B are the only classes which can access all members of class B. However, class A can access *all* members of class B; this fails your requirement that class A only access *some* of the members of class B.

Another technique would be to make class A and class B both classes in the same assembly, and the *only* classes in the assembly. Now you can mark members of B that you wish to be accessed by A as "internal", and only class A will be able to access them, since it is the only other class in the assembly.

Likely neither of these techniques are what you want. C# was not designed to have the "friend" feature of C++, as you note. My advice is to make the members of B  that you want accessed from A to be internal. This makes them accessible to all types in the current assembly, which is a small number of types written by a small number of people, all of whom you know. You can simply ask them to not use class B if you have some good, business-impacting reason to impose this requirement.

The C# type system was not designed to be able to represent and enforce every possible relationship between coworkers; "class B can be used by class A because I trust Albert, but I don't want Carol who works on class C to be able to re-use my work" is simply not a feature that the C# team thought was valuable enough to add to the type system. If you have a concern with Carol's use of class B, go talk to Carol.

Comment: Interesting that a problem that would be solved with `friend`-like features is solved by actually talking to people :)

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Firstly, yes the formulation of requirements is not 100% precise. I should have also mentioned I needed the `B` to be visible to others in the assembly. Next: I don't blame C# for not having `friend` (you sound a bit defensive). I just offer my naive method for people having similar requirements as I do.

Comment: Hi Eric..can't we make A class abstract and then make sealed class of B inherit it..in that case only  the protected methods of A (which the two classes have agreed upon) can be accessed only and only by B and other (private)methods would remain hidden .

Comment: @kyle: FIrst off, you seem to have gotten the classes backwards. The question was whether a class A could be the sole user of a method of B; your proposal suggests that a class B can be the user of methods of A. Second, I don't understand your proposal. What stops a third class from existing which also accesses the protected members? Third, it is rare for "friend" classes to have an "is a kind of" relationship between them; in fact, the point of this mechanism in C++ is to share functionality *without* inheritance.